# Cannot get Java @StoredProcedure to work, could not prepare statement

Tags: entity, java-stored-procedures

## Hi,

I having problem with @StoredProcedureQuery just getting the error "could not prepare statement"? I am not sure why storedprocedure will not run , just keep getting this error:

**"Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Function "SP_ARCHIVE_OLD_BOOKS" not found; SQL statement: call sp_archive_old_books(?,?)  [90022-193]"**

**Named parameters are used for a callable statement, but database metadata indicates named parameters are not supported**

```
@Entity
@Cacheable(value = true)
@Table(name = "Book")
@NamedStoredProcedureQuery(name = "archiveOldBooks", procedureName = "sp_archive_books",
    parameters = {
            @StoredProcedureParameter(name = "archiveDate", mode = ParameterMode.IN, type = Date.class),
            @StoredProcedureParameter(name = "warehouse", mode = ParameterMode.IN, type = String.class),
            @StoredProcedureParameter(name = "maxBookArchived", mode = ParameterMode.INOUT, type = Integer.class)
    })
@NamedQuery(name = FIND_ALL_BOOKS, query = "select b from Book b")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "SEQ_BOOK", initialValue = 50)

public class Book {

public static final String FIND_ALL_BOOKS = "book.findAllBooks";

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "SEQ_BOOK")
private int id;

@NotNull
@Min(1)
private Integer quantity;
@NotNull
@AllItemTypes
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private ItemType itemType;
@NotNull
@Title
private String title;
@NotNull
@Price
private Float price;
@NotNull
@Description
private String description;
@NotNull
@Isbn
private String isbnNumber;
@NotNull
@InitDate
private Date initDate;
@NotNull(message = "Invalid illustration is set to null")
private Boolean illustrations;
@NotNull
@PageNumber
private Integer numberOfPages;
@NotNull
@Version
@Min(1)
private Integer version;
@NotNull
@Author
private String author;
@NotNull
@Min(1519)
private Integer year;

// ======================================
// =            Constructors            =
// ======================================

public Book(){

}

public Book(Integer quantity, ItemType itemType, String title, Float price, String description, String isbnNumber, Date initDate, Boolean illustrations, Integer numberOfPages, Integer version, String author, Integer year) {
    this.quantity = quantity;
    this.itemType = itemType;
    this.title = title;
    this.price = price;
    this.description = description;
    this.isbnNumber = isbnNumber;
    this.initDate = initDate;
    this.illustrations = illustrations;
    this.numberOfPages = numberOfPages;
    this.version = version;
    this.author = author;
    this.year = year;
}

public static String getFindAllBooks() {
    return FIND_ALL_BOOKS;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public Integer getQuantity() {
    return quantity;
}

public void setQuantity(Integer quantity) {
    this.quantity = quantity;
}

public ItemType getItemType() {
    return itemType;
}

public void setItemType(ItemType itemType) {
    this.itemType = itemType;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public Float getPrice() {
    return price;
}

public void setPrice(Float price) {
    this.price = price;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

public String getIsbnNumber() {
    return isbnNumber;
}

public void setIsbnNumber(String isbnNumber) {
    this.isbnNumber = isbnNumber;
}

public Date getInitDate() {
    return initDate;
}

public void setInitDate(Date initDate) {
    this.initDate = initDate;
}

public Boolean getIllustrations() {
    return illustrations;
}

public void setIllustrations(Boolean illustrations) {
    this.illustrations = illustrations;
}

public Integer getNumberOfPages() {
    return numberOfPages;
}

public void setNumberOfPages(Integer numberOfPages) {
    this.numberOfPages = numberOfPages;
}

public Integer getVersion() {
    return version;
}

public void setVersion(Integer version) {
    this.version = version;
}

public String getAuthor() {
    return author;
}

public void setAuthor(String author) {
    this.author = author;
}

public Integer getYear() {
    return year;
}

public void setYear(Integer year) {
    this.year = year;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Book{" +
            "id=" + id +
            ", quantity=" + quantity +
            ", itemType=" + itemType +
            ", title='" + title + '\'' +
            ", price=" + price +
            ", description='" + description + '\'' +
            ", isbnNumber='" + isbnNumber + '\'' +
            ", initDate=" + initDate +
            ", illustrations=" + illustrations +
            ", numberOfPages=" + numberOfPages +
            ", version=" + version +
            ", author='" + author + '\'' +
            ", year=" + year +
            '}';
     }
}

public abstract class AbstractPeristEntityClass {
protected static EntityManagerFactory emf =   Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME);
protected EntityManager em;
protected EntityTransaction tx;

@Before
public void initEntityManager() throws Exception {
    em = emf.createEntityManager();
    tx = em.getTransaction();
}

@After
public void closeEntityManager() throws SQLException {
    if (em != null) em.close();
}

protected Long getRandomId() {
    return Math.abs(new Random().nextLong());
    }
}

public interface Constants {
 String PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME = "TEST";
}

public class Book_v2_IT extends AbstractPeristEntityClass {
@Test
public void shouldCallANamedStoredProcedureQuery() throws Exception {

    StoredProcedureQuery query = em.createNamedStoredProcedureQuery("archiveOldBooks");

    // Set the parameters and execute
    query.setParameter("archiveDate", new Date());
    query.setParameter("maxBookArchived", 1000);
    query.execute();
}

@Test
public void shouldCallAStoredProcedureQuery() throws Exception {

    StoredProcedureQuery query = em.createStoredProcedureQuery("sp_archive_old_books");
    query.registerStoredProcedureParameter("archiveDate", Date.class, ParameterMode.IN);
    query.registerStoredProcedureParameter("maxBookArchived", Integer.class, ParameterMode.IN);

    // Set the parameters and execute
    query.setParameter("archiveDate", new Date());
    query.setParameter("maxBookArchived", 1000);
    query.execute();
  }
}
```